# Why don't I get the Windows Form GUI when running my app?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2015
Version 14.0.24720.00 Update 1
Microsoft .NET Framework Version 4.6.01038

I choose New Project > Windows >  Windows Forms Application.
And I am presented with a Windows Form in design.
So far, so good.

For testing purposes, I place a Exit button on it and coded a Application.Exit()
I click on run and watch a totally different Windows Form, like a WPF form.
When I change the FormBorderStyle to Fixed 3D, I see the change happen in design, but not when I ran it.
It stays with that WPF-style

I don't want this to happen, how do I get the form in runtime to look as in my design?
(And no, I don't want a WPF form nor learn xaml coding).

The designer.cs:

```
        // Form1
        // 
        this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(366, 256);
        this.Controls.Add(this.button1);
        this.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.Fixed3D;
        this.Name = "Form1";
        this.Text = "Form1";
        this.ResumeLayout(false);
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe its better to share screenshot, Also the part of your `Form1.Designer.cs` that your forms properties are set.

Comment: Added part of designer.cs and picture.

Comment: Yes, I recently got this OS.

Comment: It's normal, the style of non-client area of a window is controlled by OS, All windows in Windows 10 looks like the picture. If you run your application on a Windows 8 or 7 you will see it like other windows 8 or 7 windows.

Comment: Now I am feeling stuppid  *blush*, but many thanks for your answer sir.

Comment: To customize the painting of non-client area in your form, you can override `WndProc` and handle `WM_NCPAINT`. But I think this is not what you are looking for :)

Comment: Great tip!!!  
Thanks again. :)

Comment: I added more description about the different appearance. hope you find the answer useful :)

Comment: Very clear and direct answer. I marked it as the preferred answer and voted :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The style of non-client area of a `Form` is controlled by OS and all top-level forms use OS theme. But forms that are not top-level don't use OS theme. Since the form at design time is not top level, it doesn't use OS theme and it's the reason that the run-time and design-time appearance are different.

It's normal to see that window, because it's windows 10 (in picture) and all forms in Windows 10 looks like the picture. If you run your application on a Windows 8 or 7 you will see it like other forms in  8 or 7.